# Mongodb $or and $eq: [ ] not working if array is empty

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

The collection (Product) has two document:

```
[      
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5af00c72cdded465976dfc41"),
            "dates" : [{
              "start": ISODate("2018-05-01T08:21:06.152Z")
              "end": ISODate("2018-05-30T08:21:06.152Z")
            }],
            "minutes" : [ 
                {
                    "start" : 1980, //1440*1+9*60
                    "end" : 8400 // 1440*5+20*60
                }
            ]
    },
    {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5af00c72cdded465976dfc41"),
            "dates" : [],
            "minutes" : [ 
                {
                    "start" : 1980,
                    "end" : 8400
                }, 
                {
                    "start" : 9240,
                    "end" : 9720
                }
            ]
    }
]
```

I would like to make a criteria, that is looking for a product availiable at a specific period of time based on **dates** and **minutes**

A week is represnted in 1440 minutes, and days of week start from 0:sunday .... 6 Saturday.

My problem is when i have *dates* empty the document 2 is not returned, i think the problem comes from **$eq**. I tried **$exists** but it doesn't work

***Document n°1 :***

this product will be in store from 2018-05-01 to 2018-05-30 but only from Mondy (9am) to Friday (20pm)

***Document n°2 :***

1 - this product will be in store from Mondy (9am) to Friday (20pm)

```
 {
   "start" : 1980, //1440*1+9*60
   "end" : 8400 // 1440*5+20*60
 }
```

2- then in Saturday from 10 am to 18pm

```
{
  "start" : 9240, // 1440*6+10*60
  "end" : 9720 // 1440*6+18*60
}
```

My criteria is:

```
    const minutesInWeek = date.days() * 1440 + date.hours() * 60 + date.minutes();
    this.pModel.
        find({
            $and: [
                { minutes : {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        $or : [
                            { minutes: {$eq: [ ]} },
                            { $and: [{start: { $lte: minutesInWeek }}, {end: { $gt: minutesInWeek }} ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                { dates : {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        $or : [
                            { dates: {$eq: [ ]} },
                            { $and: [{start: { $lte: new Date() }}, {end: { $gt: new Date() }} ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }}
            ]
        });;
```

i would really appreciate some help with this, thanks!

Comment: Try with `{ $size: 0 }` [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/size/)

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT
I try this option but it doesn't work

Comment: Could you elaborate how "A week is represnted in 1440 minutes," ? Mongodb uses Gregorian calendar, which counts 10,080 minutes in a UTC week.

Comment: Also 'dates' in the first document is not a valid array. Is it an object, or an array of objects?

Comment: @AlexBlex Right Right it's a typo when I write the post 
but in my tests I use  a valid the right one , its an array of objects

Comment: Dear oubchid, please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic We don't have your tests. All we see is what's in your post. Please review the question. Can you reproduce the problem with **only** information you've posted?

Answer (score 1):

you should probably use `$or` first of `elemMatch` of `dates`

```
this.pModel.
        find({
            $and: [
                { minutes : {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        $or : [
                            { minutes: {$eq: [ ]} },
                            { $and: [{start: { $lte: minutesInWeek }}, {end: { $gt: minutesInWeek }} ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }},
                {
                    $or: [
                        {
                            $where: "this.dates.length == 0"
                        },
                        {
                            dates : {
                                $elemMatch: {
                                    $or : [
                                        { $and: [{start: { $lte: new Date() }}, {end: { $gt: new Date() }} ] }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })
```

Comment: this works but it return also products that do not match the first condition (dates and minutes ) :)
I also get products with empty array dates

Comment: You can use this last condition inside elements match or condition